# How to guarantee permanent administrator priviligies to my WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, uac, administrator

I have read a lot of articles for UAC evelation in Windows 7 and so on, but I did not suceed in finding an answer to my question : How to guarantee that my application will be always "Run as administrator" , I am looking for some code snippet or something else. Any help will be appreciated. / And please don't spam with posts like : "Are you sure that you need this priviligies and access" - Yes I am sure the application needs them.

Comment: I guess you do that this way. Double Click "My Project" in Solution Explorer and Click UAC Settings button. Then Modify app.manifest file to have 'requireAdministrator' instead of 'asInvoker' and save.... see this demo... http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=voLjlrvvIU4

Comment: AngelWPF, your comment should be an answer

Comment: @Yoan: I have yet to understand the inner workings of the brain of someone asking for advice, yet manages to be rude to the people who are going to share their knowledge and time for free with a total stranger.

Comment: And I can't understand the inner workings of the brain of someone who was kindly asked not to spam , and inspite of this he actually does spam.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This MSDN article explains how to be UAC friendly:
[Teach Your Apps To Play Nicely With Windows Vista User Account Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163486.aspx)

Chapter [Marking Required Privileges Using an Application Manifest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163486.aspx#S7) is what you are looking for.

Comment: The same comment , thanks for the good article , but the things that I found there are the same as anywhere writing requireAdministrator in the manifest ... but as I commented , I want to avoid this dialog because my application will be run as shell and can't ask user for permisions , so can't run as shell because it need administrator rules.

Comment: +1 for correct answer. Note that if UAC is disabled then the application will not be able to elevate. Also note that if UAC is enabled, and the user is a standard user, they will have to get someone from IT four buildings over to walk over and enter their credentials (which means the user can't run the app for an hour or so). More likely IT will say, "*No, you can't run it. Tough.*". Which leads to the *better* solution: don't require ask for elevation when you don't need to be an administrator.

Answer (score 7):

Add an app manifest to your app with the following section:

```
<security>
  <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />    
  </requestedPrivileges>
</security>
```

Comment: Yes but , this prompts a dialog to the user if he agrees to give access to the application , the thing I am looking for is how to grant it without asking the user.

Comment: @Yoan Petrov, you can't. But you can create a windows service with administrative privileges and communicate with it from your app. This way your app won't require elevated privileges at all.

Comment: Dmitry is there any way to do this by one time click , for example 1 time dialog for user rights and granting user rights "forever" , because I am not into windows service and haven't ever worked with something like that , but if there is no other way I will have to do it.

Comment: @YoanPetrov as far as I know, there is no such way. Technically speaking, implementing app+service scheme will give this effect: you'll be asked to elevate rights during setup. It is also possible to check if service exists on the first run and if it doesn't ask for priveleges and install it, though it's a bit more complex. Writing a windows service in .NET is an easy task so I urge you to seriously consider this option. You can find info on winservices here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: +1 for example format. Also +1 for Dmitry's mention that you cannot white-list an application. If application's could white-list themselves then there would be no incentive for them to fix their application.

Answer (score 2):

Windows does not have the capability to grant an *application* administrative privileges; permissions are granted by *user*.

If the user running your application does not have administrative permissions, then your application will not have administrative permissions.

A program cannot be "guaranteed permanent" administrator permissions because a program wishes it. The *user* must be granted the permissions.

- you can engineer your application to not require administrative privileges :)
- you can *advertise* that your application wants administrative permissions

  - with UAC off the request *cannot* be honored :(
  - with UAC on the request *might not* be honored :(

But the request that an **application** be granted administrative privileges is not possible.

Comment: For the record, it is not strictly speaking true to say that with UAC off the request cannot be honored; it would be more accurate to say that it is ignored.  The application will still have administrative privilege if the user does.

Comment: @Harry Johnston: Point taken. Although if the user is administrator, then there's no need to guarantee anything :P

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, your application is going to be the user shell, i.e., it will replace Windows Explorer.  There are various ways you could bypass UAC in this scenario, for example, by using a credential manager to capture the user's credentials and use them to create a new token, or by hooking the LogonUser function and capturing the unmodified token.

However, the simplest approach by far would be to disable UAC.  Unless the user will be running Internet Explorer or another program that takes advantage of UAC sandboxing, there is probably no reason to leave UAC turned on in your scenario.

Comment: +1 for configuring the kiosk machine the way you want it. But not even Microsoft's Explorer shell disables UAC. And a custom kiosk is a case where UAC should definitely *not* be disabled.

Comment: @Ian, I don't think the OPs scenario is a kiosk.  Naturally, UAC shouldn't be disabled on a kiosk machine - but the automatically logged-on user shouldn't be an administrator, either.

Comment: The OP said he was going to be running a customized shell. i cannot imagine any end user would want an application to replace Explorer; hence my thinking it's a kiosk.

Comment: @Ian, I'm thinking it's a dedicated machine, perhaps one operating machinery or a scientific instrument.  I should probably have asked for clarification first, though. :-)

Comment: Same thing in my book; you're configuring a PC for a custom standalone setup. OP needs to decide if he wants the logged in user to be an administrator or not. If the "shell" runs as an administrator, then every program it launches will be run as an administrator. You can just save a step and run the logged in user as an administrator.

Comment: @Ian, I was presuming that the logged in user would be an administrator, and that the OP just wanted to recover the admin privilege that UAC takes away.